# HID USB Keyboard Caps Lock

Tags: keyboard, usb, hid

In according to [this pdf](https://usb.org/sites/default/files/hut1_4.pdf)

ID 39 --> Keyboard Caps Lock (Implemented as a non-locking key; sent as member of an array)

ID 82 --> Keyboard Locking Caps Lock (Implemented as a locking key; sent as a toggle button. Available for legacy support; however, most systems should use the non-locking
version of this key)

I'm losing my mind with "non-locking" words.
What is the difference?

In my mind they are only different codes between legacy and not legacy, but with the same button layout and same function.

Comment: Historically, some keyboards when you pressed capslock, it was on, pressing capslock again wouldn't turn it off. Instead you had to press a different key like shift in order to disable it. I _imagine_ that the locking caps lock is referring to that type of capslock. Indeed this is _still_ an option in windows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L5ml.png. IOW, a locking key is one that stays down once pressed, a non-locking key doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This **Keyboard Locking Caps Lock** (Usage `0007:0082`) is not used in practice on any modern keyboard hardware and AFAIK its support is not implemented in any software including Windows.

I think it was modeled after latching Caps Lock (Shift Lock) key that was found on some vintage keyboards.

Example: https://deskthority.net/wiki/Cherry_MX_Lock